# SciLab: Return mouse click location in imshow window

Tags: image-processing, scilab, mouseclick-event

I'm using SciLab 5.5.2, and I have installed SIVP.  When I use imshow to display an image, the image appears in a TK window, and there is an additional empty graphics figure window.  I want to click on the image to return the coordinate of the click to a variable.  I have tried the functions xclick, xgetmouse, and locate.  Each one works fine with a regular graphics window, like one that appears from the figure or plot command.

Here is example code:

```
im = imread("C:\Users\jmcsc\Documents\Ann\JH.jpg");
imshow(im); // from SIVP

// wait for mouse click in figure window, 0 = left mouse button:
xMouse = locate(1);
// [ibutton, xcoord, ycoord, iwin, cbmenu] = xclick(0);
// [rep, win] = xgetmouse([%t, %f]);
```

When I run the code and click on the image in the TK window, nothing happens.  If I click on the empty graphics window, SciLab processes the mouse click, and the script finishes executing.  How do I either get the image to show in a regular graphics window or get one of the mouse-click functions to work with SIVP imshow's TK window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need image processing features in Scilab you should first migrate to Scilab 6.0.2 then install the [IPCV atoms module](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/IPCV/2.0). This module has all the features of SIVP and is better integrated into Scilab as it does not use Tk, hence you will be able to use `xgetmouse` after `imshow`.

Comment: Originally, I installed 6.0.2, but some atoms like SIVP aren't compatible with that version, so I backed up to 5.5.2.  I will try going back to 6.0.2 and installing IPCV.

Comment: Worked perfectly.